# Bootstrap, how to keep a div element under an img-fluid?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Want to have a responsive displayed image with a div-element under the image.
What I got is an image that can overlap the div-element. How to fix this in Bootstrap?
Simplified it looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 pt-5 pl-lg-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="container">
            <img id="image" class="img-fluid" src="~/images/myImage.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="py-3 py-lg-4">
            This text should always be displayed under the image
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  height: 245px;
  width: 310px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I hope this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872689/correct-way-to-wrap-text-under-image-in-bootstrap-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code has several issues. Let's go step by step:

1. Having a look at [Bootstrap's `.img-fluid`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/images/#responsive-images) gives us the information that `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` are applied to the image. Thus, setting a `height` and `width` will make your image flow over the `height` of `245px`. We have to add a `max-height: 100%` to the `#image`.
2. You define a `width: 310px` and overwrite it two lines below with `width: 100%`
3. You use `.row` but do not include columns (`.col`) inside. Have a look at [Bootstrap's Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/).
4. I do not understand the `#image` css code but this should be inherently given.

In order to get your targeted result, your code could look something like this:

```css
#container {
  height: 245px;
  width: 310px;
  position: relative;
}

#image {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 pt-5 pl-lg-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="container">
        <img id="image" class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/450" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="py-3 py-lg-4">
        This text should always be displayed under the image
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For better visibility have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6fb2mhvz/16/).

Below are some screenshots of the result for different image sizes.

`450px x 450px`:

[image: Result for 450x450]

`450px x 800px`:

[image: Result for 450x800]

`800px x 450px`:

[image: Result for 800x450]